# prettier seems to not working in VScode (python)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, prettier-vscode

I don't actually know how these thins work, apparently prettier explains how to make it the main formatter on their page:

```
{
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  }
}
```

but i dont even know how to set this things.
anyways, my question is, after i complete my writing, when i type ctrl + s (save) on my vscode, it used to make it, well, prettier. but now it doesnt change anything (and it is not pretty at all).

now, at the bottom right of the screen, i see this:
[what i see on my bottom right corner for prettier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5n9By.png)

and if i click that, ahem, empty set (?) image next to prettier, it becomes a double tick, but it exist my coding area and enter the output section:
[after i click on the thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRypB.png)

and if i click back to my coding area, it again becomes an, well, empty set (?) symbol.

all the help is appraciated.

ps: this is my first question, please go easy on my

sincerly

Comment: Please read the VSCode documentation on how to set preferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably missing something in your settings. VSCode allows you to edit your settings through GUI or text (using JSON syntax).
Go to your settings using the GUI and type: "Format", then make sure you have enabled the option "Editor: Format On Save".

[image: VSCode config]

Depending your formatter settings, when you save a file it should work as you expected.